# BigQuery Times Out on 2-Table JOIN

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I’m trying to join two tables in BigQuery but it hits the 6 hour query execution time limit. For context:

- The primary table is ~150M rows; the joined table is ~250M rows.
- It’s a simple `SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b` with equality comparison on three columns (as `OR`s). These three columns are strings ranging from 10-80 or so characters in length.
- The same query with the same schemas for those tables, but with a sample of only 100K rows each, works quickly and without issue.
- **Tried:** Running with fewer join clauses (3 instead of 9), enabling large results
- **Expected:** BQ to render a result, eventually
- **Actual:** Timeout

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: it would be extremely usefull to see the exact query, especially the `JOIN`/`WHERE` conditions.

In addition,  you didn't give any information about indexing and column types of the columns you are comparing

Comment: In addition to the above comment, please add the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query to your question

Comment: How many rows do you expect after the join? Always use the larger table first in the join. Instead of `or` in the `on` statement, please try to use two joins.